# ZeroMQ issues with example networking patterns; Paranoid Pirate and Majordomo

Tags: c++, zeromq

I'm trying to get the ZeroMQ examples [Paranoid Pirate](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#Robust-Reliable-Queuing-Paranoid-Pirate-Pattern) and [Majordomo](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#Service-Oriented-Reliable-Queuing-Majordomo-Pattern) working in C++.  The code is available at GitHub [ZeroMQ examples C++ Source Code](https://github.com/imatix/zguide/tree/master/examples/C%2B%2B).

Both examples contain a REQ to ROUTER connection (amongst other connections) by which a client program communicates with a  message queue (Paranoid Pirate) or a message broker (Majordomo).  In both of these example patterns I am unable to establish communication between the REQ and ROUTER sockets.

I have compiled and run Paranoid Pirate on Windows 7 64 bit using Visual C++ and ZeroMQ-3.2.3 and also on Debian (Wheezy) 32 bit using g++ and ZeroMQ-4.0.4. I have also compiled and run Majordomo on the Debian system.

I think there is some fundamental problem in establishing the REQ-ROUTER communications and/or polling. In both example patterns the client is not communicating properly; but as I'm trying to learn ZeroMQ networking from the examples it is proving testing to also debug them at the same time.

I have found there to be some issues with the time-out settings in the example code, for example where a time-out of 2500 milliseconds is multiplied by 1000 to give a timeout of 2500 SECONDS; which gives the appearance of nothing happening when observing the console output, but in reality it's just a very long wait.

Does anyone know how to get the Paranoid Pirate and Majordomo patterns operating as intended in C++?

Comment: The timeout being multiplied by 1000 was probably because of an older version of ZeroMQ, which used microseconds instead of milliseconds.
Have you experimented with a single REQ-ROUTER socket pair communication channel? Maybe you could also try sniffing the network to see what messages are being passed around.

Comment: Definitely a good idea, as suggested, to try just a simple example first.  Run one of the first examples, just a simple rep/req, and see if you can successfully send/receive messages.  Then use a req/router example from earlier in the guide.

Comment: No problems with simple REQ-REP examples.  Ran this alternative example http://thisthread.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/very-simple-req-router-example.html (albeit using zeromq-3.2.3) and it did not complete as intended and did not report "ROUTER done".  Suggesting to me that the messages did not get through the REQ-ROUTER connection.

Comment: Ran the alternative example: [Simple REQ-ROUTER](http://thisthread.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/very-simple-req-router-example.html) this time using zeromq-2.2.0 and it worked fully and reported "ROUTER done".  Seems there is some breaking change between zeromq versions.